# Can't upload a photo to Appcelerator Cloud Service using HttpWebRequest in C#

Tags: c#, upload, httpwebrequest, cloud, appcelerator

I'm developing an application in C# that connects to Appcelerator Cloud Service, so far I can make queries and create custom objects, now the problem is when I try to create a photo in ACS. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874410/webrequest-post-with-both-file-and-parameters) link and modified my code like this:

```
Image img = pbPhoto.Image;
img.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\tmp.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); //saving the image temporally in hard drive

url = "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/photos/create.json?key=appkey&_session_id=" + session;
HttpWebRequest wrGetUrl = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

String boundary = "B0unD-Ary";
wrGetUrl.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
wrGetUrl.Method = "POST";

String postData = "--" + boundary + "\nContent-Disposition: form-data\n\n";;
postData += "\n--" + boundary + "\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\" filename=\"" + Application.StartupPath + "\\tmp.jpg" + "\"\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\n\n";
byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

byte[] filedata = null;
using (BinaryReader readerr = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(Application.StartupPath + "\\tmp.jpg")))
    filedata = readerr.ReadBytes((int)readerr.BaseStream.Length);

wrGetUrl.ContentLength = byteArray.Length + filedata.Length;
wrGetUrl.GetRequestStream().Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
wrGetUrl.GetRequestStream().Write(filedata, 0, filedata.Length);

objStream = wrGetUrl.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
reader = new StreamReader(objStream);
```

I tried this but I got the following error

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

I checked my ACS log but the request didn't show up (guess because it was a 500 error). What should I change in my code to upload the photo and crete the photo in ACS? Thanks for any help you may give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution for this problem:

```
byte[] filedata = null;
using (BinaryReader readerr = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(pathToImage)))
    filedata = readerr.ReadBytes((int)readerr.BaseStream.Length);
string boundary = "-_1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
request.ContentType = string.Format("multipart/form-data; boundary={0}", boundary);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);   
writer.Write("--");
writer.WriteLine(boundary);
writer.WriteLine(@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""{0}""; filename=""{1}""", "your_name", "your_photo_file_name");
writer.WriteLine(@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
writer.WriteLine(@"Content-Length: " + filedata .Length);
writer.WriteLine();
writer.Flush();
Stream output = writer.BaseStream;
output.Write(filedata , 0, filedata .Length);
output.Flush();
writer.WriteLine();
writer.Write("--");
writer.Write(boundary);
writer.WriteLine("--");
writer.Flush();
```

**EDIT:** I changed the way I wrote the headers into the RequestStream, the way I was writing it wasn't the proper one to send a picture to Appcelerator Cloud Service, by sending requests through curl and checking the Log in ACS I was able to come up with the right headers.

Hope this may help anyone with similar problems.

Comment: what was exactly the problem? you didnt specified what u changed to make it work.

Comment: well I wasn't able to upload the picture into ACS, I added the details of how I found out what kind of headers ACS received when I uploaded a photo with curl.